# How to record webcam with audio on ubuntu 22.04 from cli?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording, video-recording

Command to start recording audio and video (from webcam) using command line. Preferably using ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -t 00:00:20 -vcodec libx264 record.mp4
```

- The -f defines the format, pulse for audio and v4l2(Video 4 Linux 2).
- The -ac defines the audio channels, in this case 2.
- The -i defines
  the input, default for audio and the webcam for video.
- The -t defines
  the duration of the recording, in this case 20 seconds.
- The -vcodec
  defines the output video codec, since it is an mp4 file it is set to
  libx264 (H.264)
- Audio should default to AAC so -acodec is not needed.

https://dev.to/ethand91/how-to-record-webcam-video-and-audio-using-ffmpeg-419c